# Node MySQL two queries in nested async loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js, node-mysql

I need to make two DB queries inside of async loops. I use `node-mysql` and `async.js`.

Here is an example of my code:

```
async.every(firstArray, (first, firstCB) => {
  async.every(secondArray, (second, secondCB) => {
    async.every(thirdArray, (third, thirdCB) => {
      model.getUsers(third, (res) => {
         model.insert(res.stuff, () => {
           thirdCB()
         })
       })
     }, (err) => {
       secondCB()
     });
    }, (err) => {
     thirdCB()
    })
  }, () => {
  firstCB()
}, () => {
  // done 
})
```

The itereting works well. My problem is in the last loop where Im doing two queries: `console.log .. considering thirdArray.length === 3`

```
..getting users
..getting users
..getting users
..inserting stuff
..inserting stuff
..inserting stuff
```

Why so? Im calling the thirdCB after the second query recently.

I even tried with i.e. `async.waterfall([getUser, insert], thirdCB)` but with the same result.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here you can see an example: https://repl.it/@froston/NodeMultipleAsyncLoops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799175/async-waterfall-in-a-for-loop-in-node-js)!

The solution to this is using [`eachLimit`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html?#eachLimit), setting the limit to `1`, instead of `every`. That will limit the amount of async operation per item.